# select from sqlite table where rowid in list using python sqlite3 — DB-API 2.0

Tags: python, sqlite

The following works:

```
>>> cursor.execute("select * from sqlitetable where rowid in (2,3);")
```

The following doesn't:

```
>>> cursor.execute("select * from sqlitetable where rowid in (?) ", [[2,3]] )
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Is there a way to pass in a python list without having to format it into a string first ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Each value must be given its own parameter mark (`?`).
Since the argument list can (presumably) have arbitrary length, you must use string formating to build the correct number of parameter marks. Happily, that isn't so hard:

```
args=[2,3]
sql="select * from sqlitetable where rowid in ({seq})".format(
    seq=','.join(['?']*len(args)))

cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Comment: `args` should always be a list or tuple of arguments. The arguments may be strings, but `args` itself never.

Comment: Since this answer is 5 years old...is this still valid? Does pysqlite still not support `IN` for a list?

Comment: Is there a limit in the number of values we can provide to execute?

Comment: @Srikan yes there is, you have to pay attention to `SQLITE_LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER`  limit (https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_limit_attached.html#sqlitelimitvariablenumber) which is by default set to 999. I.e. you cannot have more than 999 `?` in the query

Comment: @JohnyGomez – with an out-of-the-box Python 3.9 I did a primary key select with 41k placeholders (with incredible performance). How can I check the compile settings I'm using implicitly from Python's sqlite3 module?

Comment: @flaschbier I believe `PRAGMA compile_options;` will give you compile-time settings including `MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER`.

Comment: @flaschbier in Python 3.11+ you can now do `dbcon.getlimit(sqlite3.SQLITE_LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER)`.  I seem to get 250k by default, which matches the value coming back from the `PRAGMA`

Comment: @SamMason – still have to to that version hop, but very much appreciated <3

Answer (score 16):

In Python 3.6 you can also build queries with the f strings:

```
args=[2, 3]
query = f"SELECT * FROM sqlitetable WHERE rowid in ({','.join(['?']*len(args))})"
cursor.execute(query, args)
```

Comment: What if you want to use named arguments?

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite natively supports only the types TEXT, INTEGER, REAL, BLOB and NULL. If you want to use other types you must add support for them yourself. The detect_types parameter and the using custom converters registered with the module-level register_converter() function allow you to easily do that.

As described before, SQLite supports only a limited set of types natively.

To use other Python types with SQLite, you must adapt them to one of the sqlite3 module’s supported types for SQLite: one of NoneType, int, float, str, bytes.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#using-adapters-to-store-additional-python-types-in-sqlite-databases

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include more than one `IN` clause with a query along with other named parameters and came up with a helper method that would let me do:

```
params = {'mn': 5, 'mx': 15}
in_a = sql_in([1,2,3], params, prefix='a')
in_b = sql_in([5,6,7], params, prefix='b')
query = (
    "SELECT rowid, name FROM tbl "
    "WHERE value BETWEEN :mn AND :mx"
    f" AND (alpha IN {in_a} OR beta IN {in_b})"
)
dbcon.execute(query, params)
```

Which uses this helper method:

```
def sql_in(values, params, *, prefix='in'):
    """Generate an IN clause for SQLite using named placeholders.
    Given values=[1,2,3], will return:
        '(:in0,:in1,:in2)'
    after doing:
        params.update({'in0':1,'in1':2,'in2':3})
    If you're using this multiple times with a single dbcon.execute(),
    you need to give each one a distinct prefix, e.g.:
      params = {}
      in_a = sql_in([1,2,3], params, prefix='a')
      in_b = sql_in([5,6,7], params, prefix='b')
      dbcon.execute(f'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a IN {in_a} OR b IN {in_b}', params)
    """
    def inner():
        yield '('
        delim = ':'
        for i, val in enumerate(values):
            key = f'{prefix}{i}'
            assert key not in params
            params[key] = val
            yield delim
            yield key
            delim = ',:'
        yield ')'
    return ''.join(inner())
```