# SQL Select from many-to-one

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, having-clause

I have two tables containing a one-to-many relationship.  How should I select the "one" side given information for the "many" side?  I'm using [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org).

Let's say our first table, T1, is about cars and the second table, T2, is about the imperfections in each car.

Let's say we can describe the imperfections with an integer.

So we have:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
       [Other columns]
);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
       carId INTEGER REFERENCES T1(id),
       imperfection INTEGER
);
```

We have data about a few cars and each one has a number of imperfections.

Given a list of integers representing imperfections, how can I select the cars that have exactly this set of imperfections?  For example, let's say I have [1,5,7] as the list of imperfections, how can I find out that matches car 19?

If it's helpful, I expect that there is only one match for each unique set of imperfections.

This question is similar to that in a [DBA Stack Exchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28431/many-to-one-subselection-in-single-query), however in the previous question the number of imperfections were known.  In this question, I do not know the number of imperfections.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use HAVING with COUNT.

Comment: What do you mean *I do not know the number of imperfections*? You do have a list like [1,5,7].

Comment: @forpas In the linked question, there were always exactly two imperfections.  As a consequence, the answers hard-coded that assumption.  In this case, the number of imperfections is not known in advance.  It may be, for example, that the list is [1,5,7,8] for the next query.

Comment: Fine then, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Assuming you have no duplicates:

```
select carid
from t2
group by carid
having sum(case when imperfection in (1, 5, 7) then 1 else 0 end) = 3;
```

This finds only cars that have exactly 1, 5, and 7.  If you wanted any car that had these -- and perhaps others -- you can simplify this to:

```
select carid
from t2
where imperfection in (1, 5, 7)
group by carid
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: Your first solution could also have been selected as the accepted answer.  Unfortunately, I understand I can only accept one answer.  Thanks for your extremely speedy assistance.

Comment: @MatthewWalker . . . Other than being first, it does something a bit different from GMB's answer.  I interpret the question as wanting only 1, 5, and 7 as imperfections, and no others.  That is the basis for the first answer and the subsequent query that expands upon that.

Comment: I feel that `sum(case when imperfection in (1, 5, 7) then 1 else 0 end) = 3` is equivalent to `sum(imperfection in (1, 5, 7)) = 3 and sum(imperfection not in (1, 5, 7)) = 0`.  (Although your answer is most likely computationally more efficient).  Do you agree?  If these two clauses are equivalent, then I feel the two answers are equivalent.  Or did I miss something?

Comment: Given the advantage of only having to pass in the list of imperfections once (rather than twice for GMB's approach), I have changed my mind and gone with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select carId
from t2
where imperfection in (1, 5, 7)
group by carId
having count(*) = 3
```

This brings cars that have all 3 imperfections. If you want to exclude cars that have other imperfections as well, then:

```
select carId
from t2
group by carId
having
    sum(imperfection in (1, 5, 7)) = 3
    and sum(imperfection not in (1, 5, 7)) = 0
```

Comment: I went with your second approach.  Although I wasn't clear in my question, I was looking for an exact match, which your answer provides in a very understandable manner.  Thanks.

Comment: For those who are interested in applying the above solution using SQLite under Python, I found it a challenge to pass in the list of imperfection integers, however this stackoverflow answer was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5766293/562930

Comment: Because this answer required that I pass the list of imperfections twice, I changed my mind and went with @GordonLinoff's answer.  I still feel this answer is more easily understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of imperfections as a sorted comma separated string like `'1,5,7'` then you can do it with `group_concat()` window function:

```
select carId
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by carId order by imperfection desc) rn,
    group_concat(imperfection) over (partition by carId order by imperfection) imperfections
  from T2
)   
where rn = 1 and imperfections = '1,5,7'
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7HyjHti4fhLornPGevXLQj/0).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting alternative approach and especially for the demo.