# How to safely use the IN command with Python SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there a way to dynamically use the SQLite `IN` command in Python without providing the exact number of placeholders?

For instance, let's say I'm trying to get:

```
SELECT
*
FROM mytable
WHERE somecol IN (1, 3, 4, 7, 9)
```

In Python, a placeholder is a tuple of at least length 1, but I'm not sure *how* (or even ***if*** it is possible) to use them with the `IN` command. I have tried pure tuples, stringed tuples and pure strings, both free and enclosed, all to no avail:

```py
In [1]: import sqlite3
   ...: conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
   ...: cur = conn.cursor()
   ...: l = [(i, chr(i+64)) for i in range(1, 11)]
   ...: cur.execute('CREATE TABLE mytable (somecol INTEGER, char TEXT)')
   ...: cur.executemany('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?, ?)', l)
   ...: conn.commit()

In [2]: tup = ((1, 3, 4, 7, 9),)
   ...: cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN ?', tup)
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-195e99af7b4f> in <module>
----> 1 cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN ?', tup).fetchall()

OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

In [3]: cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN (?)', tup).fetchall()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a6c2d28cce18> in <module>
----> 1 cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN (?)', tup).fetchall()

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

In [4]: tups = tuple(str(i) for i in tup)
   ...: cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN ?', tups)
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-195e99af7b4f> in <module>
----> 1 cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN ?', tups).fetchall()

OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

In [5]: # Empty list due to trying to fetch a somecol string value of "(1, 3, 4, 7, 9)"
   ...: cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN (?)', tups).fetchall()
Out[5]: []

In [6]: stup = (', '.join(str(i) for i in tup[0]),)
   ...: cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN ?', stup)
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-195e99af7b4f> in <module>
----> 1 cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN ?', stup).fetchall()

OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

In [7]: # Empty list due to trying to fetch a somecol string value of "1, 3, 4, 7, 9"
   ...: cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN (?)', stup).fetchall()
Out[7]: []
```

I know that if I provide `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', tup[0]).fetchall()` I will get the desired result, but that's because I know the length of `tup[0]` beforehand and adjusted the cursor accordingly. However, this will break down on applications where I can't anticipate that.

I'm almost sure this is actually not feasbile in Python, but I'm wondering why it is and should be so?

Comment: I can only tell you the reason: Because the underlying C/C++ API doesn't support this, see https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

Comment: `tup = (1, 3, 4, 7, 9) ; cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN " + str(tup))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join all the values in comma separated string:

```
tup = (1, 3, 4, 7, 9)
s = ",".join(str(i) for i in tup)
```

and then use the operator `LIKE` instead of `IN`:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || somecol || ',%';"
cur.execute(sql, (s,)).fetchall()
```

This way you need only 1 placeholder.

Comment: Not exactly a neat syntax, but hey, that's on SQLite for not having a CONCAT function ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ thanks

Comment: `||` is the concatenation operator for SQLite.

Comment: I know, I just find it counterproductive to use a verbose statement like SQLite's instead of a readily available function in other flavours.

Comment: Do you really consider this verbose? It is a very simple sql statement.

Comment: Just a tad bit, but at the same time it's very ingenious. Will probably mark it as the correct answer if no one comes forward with another plausible solution.

Comment: Composing SQL strings from input is dangerous, because it exposes your application to SQL injection. See https://xkcd.com/327/ for an illustration. Rather create a suitable "?,?,?,..." string for placeholdes like the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence placeholder supported by other databases isn't supported by sqlite.

To get around this you just generate as many single placeholders in a sequence as needed. Via like: `'(' + ','.join('?'*len(v)) + ')'`

Comment: It's a simple solution, though it requires preparing the query string before executing. Still better than simply formatting the string altogether.

Comment: @manoelpqueiroz Evereyting is better than opening your application to SQL injection... cf. https://xkcd.com/327/ ^^

Answer (score 2):

Since the argument list can don't have the same length, you must use string formating to build the correct number of parameter marks check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766230/select-from-sqlite-table-where-rowid-in-list-using-python-sqlite3-db-api-2-0)

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecol IN ({seq})".format( seq=','.join(['?']*len(tup[0]))),tup[0]).fetchall()
```

Comment: Formatting strings goes precisely against the developers' intended use of the module (docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: The format will be "select * from mytable where somecol in (?,?,?,?,?)