# Injection safe "SELECT FROM table WHERE column IN list;" using python3 and sqlite3

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to take a user input from an html form, and do a SELECT by matching a column to the user input, and be safe for injection. BUT I want the user input to be a comma separated list. For example, if the column is called "name" and user_input is "Alice,Bob,Carrol" I wan to execute the query

`SELECT FROM table WHERE name IN ("Alice","Bob","Carrol");`

Which means I have the same problem as in this question [select from sqlite table where rowid in list using python sqlite3 — DB-API 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766230/select-from-sqlite-table-where-rowid-in-list-using-python-sqlite3-db-api-2-0).
But of course I do not want to do string concatenation myself to avoid injections. At the same time, because there could be any number of commas in user_input, I cannot do this:

`db.execute('SELECT FROM table WHERE name IN (?,?,?)', user_input_splited)`

I looked for a way to sanitize or escape the input by hand, to be able to do something like that:

`db.execute('SELECT FROM table WHERE name IN ?', user_input_sanitized)`

But I didn't find it. What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own code to take the user's input, `split()` it by comma, then iterate through that list.  As you accept each value, push it onto *one* array, and push a literal `"?"` onto the other.

Of course, now verify that you have at least one acceptable value.

Now, construct your SQL statement by to include, say, `join(", ", $qmarks_array)` to automatically construct a string that looks like `?, ?, ? ...` with an appropriate number of question-marks.*(It won't insert any comma if there's only one element.)*  Then, having constructed the SQL statement in this way, supply the other array as input to the function which executes that query.

In this way, you supply each value as a parameter, which you should always do, *and* you allow the number of parameters to vary.

Comment: Thanks. And now I realise this is also what that other page I linked actually says to do... String concatenation is unsafe but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in sqlite is, you must give always the correct quantity of question marks in your inquiry.If you have a list or a tuple containg 3 items, you must ask for (?,?,?) items. If you ask only for one (?) you get an error like:
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
The solution is to find the quantity of items in the list and prepare a string with the correct quantity of qustion marks.
Like in the code below:

```
    list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
    question_marks=len(list1)*'?,'
    selecting="select * from products where product_id in ("+question_marks[:-1]+")"
    curr.execute(selecting,list1)
    product_list=curr.fetchall()
```